# JColorChooser to change the font color in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jcolorchooser

How to use the JColorChooser to change the font color in java swing?

Comment: Very simple task after you go through [How to use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;
     import javax.swing.*;



    public class JColorChooserExample extends JFrame
                                       implements ActionListener
     {


    private JButton b;
    private Container c;
    private Color color;

   public JColorChooserExample(String title)
    {
      super(title);

      color = Color.pink;
       c = getContentPane();
       c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      c.setBackground(color);

       c.add(new JLabel(
          "Click button to select a new background color"));
       b = new JButton("Color");
       b.setToolTipText("Click here to change color");
       b.addActionListener(this);
       c.add(b);

      addWindowListener(new MyWindowCloser());
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      color = JColorChooser.showDialog(
                  this, "Select a Background Color", color);
      if (color != null)
       {
           c.setBackground(color);
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       JColorChooserExample jcce =
           new JColorChooserExample("JColorChooser Example");
       jcce.pack();
       jcce.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

And read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html) also

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from the example that creates a JColorChooser instance and adds it to a container:

```
public class ColorChooserDemo extends JPanel ... {
public ColorChooserDemo() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    banner = new JLabel("Welcome to the Tutorial Zone!",
                        JLabel.CENTER);
    banner.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    . . .
    tcc = new JColorChooser(banner.getForeground());
    . . .
    add(tcc, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}
```

The following code registers and implements the change listener:

```
tcc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
. . .

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
Color newColor = tcc.getColor();
banner.setForeground(newColor);
}
```